# Can I write a script which will send me message when there is heavy load on my server

Tags: jmeter

when there is heavy load applied on my web application I must receive an email, If server is crashed or shutdown I can take necessary action it. How can I do it using jmeter when testing.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter comes with [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) which can send emails to individuals or groups. You can use it in conjunction with [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) and [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller), something like

- **"Normal Sampler"** - i.e. [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

  - **Assertion** to check response code, duration, presence of some text, absence of errors, etc.
- **If Controller** with the condition of `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`, special JMeter Variable which is `true` when previous sampler is successful and `false` otherwise

  - **SMTP Sampler** - to send an email

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for example SMTP and Mail Reader samplers configuration